# Probability that a size-conditioned random subset contains a specific element

Tags: probability, combinatorics, elementary-set-theory

Given a set $S = \{s_1, s_2,..., s_N \}$ and a random subset $S'$ of size $M<N$, what's the probability that $S'$ contains element $s_i$? I.e., I'm looking for an explicit expression for
$$\mathbb{P} \left( s_i \in S' |\  \lvert S' \rvert = M \right).$$

---

I guess one way to solve this would be by computing the number of subsets of size $M$ containing $s_i$, $S'_i:= \{ B \in S : s_i \in B, |B| = M \}$, and divide it by the number of possible subsets of size $M$. Anyway, I have not found a way to express this.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: It seems you know how to count all the possible subsets of size $M$. Then counting the number of subsets of size $M$ containing $s_i$ is the same as counting the possible subsets of $S \setminus \{s_i\}$ of size $M-1$.

Comment: Many thanks @FabiusWiesner! This, complemented with @jojo2699 gave me the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your idea to solve this problem is correct. The number of possible subsets of size $M$ from a set of size $N$ is simply given by the binomial coefficient, $$C_M^N=\frac{N!}{M!(N-M)!}.$$
And then you have to note that the number of subsets of size $M$ containing $s_i$ corresponds to number of subsets of size $M-1$ from a set of size $N-1$, ($s_i$ is fixed, so we consider only combinaison with other elements). Thus your probability is then simply given by,
$$P(s_i \in S' | |S'|=M)=\frac{C_{M-1}^{N-1}}{C_{M}^N}=\frac{(N-1)!}{(M-1)!(N-1-(M-1))!}\frac{M!(N-M)!}{N!}=\frac{M}{N} .$$
Hope this helps!

Comment: Many thanks @jojo2699! This is precisely what I needed :). 

This also let me answer the more general question of computing the probability that the subset S' contains another subset S'' of size $L \leq M$ as $C_{M-L}^{N-L}/C_M^N$, which doesn't simplify to N/M.